# How to stop Intellij IDEA from adding gradlew after deleting?

Tags: intellij-idea

I deleted gradle files like `gradlew`, wrapper etc except of the `gradle.build.kts` from the Intellij IDEA project.

But the IDEA keeps adding it back, how to prevent that? I don't want those files.

Comment: Why do you need to delete it?

Comment: @Andrey why do I need to keep it when just one `gradle.build.kts` is enough?

Answer (score 1):

IDE creates it when you are using Gradle wrapper for project.

If you do not want to use Gradle wrapper, you can set the local Gradle distribution in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Use Gradle from** option.

Comment: Thanks, I switched and it worked, for some time, but then the whole `build.gradle.kts` file became red in IDEA with "unresolved reference ..." errors. Running gradle from the command line works fine. Could it be that it uses different JDK, as I installed gradle with `brew` and it seems like it uses openjdk.

Comment: `but then the whole build.gradle.kts file became red in IDEA with "unresolved reference ..." errors. ` Does re-import complete successfully  at this point? Try changing **Gradle JVM** or re-import project using File | New | Project from Existing Sources... If problem remains report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT with idea.log (Help | Show Log in ... action) file and a sample project or build.gradle.kts file and screenshots showing the problem for the investigation.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but I decided that I don't need Gradle and deleted it, 
 going to use good old Maven :)